# Having an issues with fgets() and segmentation faults on last line of external file

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fgets

Here is a snippet of code from my program that is causing an segmentation error on the last line. My program is supposed to take input from a file (if that is specified by the user) or from manual input from the console. When the user inputs the sentences by the console, it works. However, when I take the sentences from an external file, I get a segmentation fault on the last line (the line where when it is completed EOF will be reached). **Assume the file is closed and the memory freed outside of this snippet**.

Here is the snippet:

```
if(inputExists == 1) {
        char *input = malloc(256);
        ip = fopen(inFile, "r");
        if(ip) {
            while(fgets(input, 256, ip) != NULL) {
                printf("%s", input);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is what is on the external file:

```
bob is working.
david is a new hire.
alice is bob's boss.
charles doesn't like bob.
```

This is the output that I get when the full program (where the option for the user taking input from an external file is selected).

```
bob is working.
david is a new hire.
alice is bob's boss.
Segmentation fault
```

If you think you need more code to find the problem let me know and I will add the full program (though to be honest it is very ugly, and messy).

Comment: So little code, so many flaws: You forget to close the file. `free` the memory. `fflush(stdout)` should show the last line. `sizeof(input)` is wrong. What do you think is the size of a pointer? You need the size of the allocated memory (**minus one**). The segfault is likely elsewhere. Use a debugger and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Why not fscanf for one string at a time? Or even fgetc. I'm fairly confident fgetc consumes and stores newline characters too. So many easier ways that could've avoided a lot of simple errors.

Comment: `sizeof(input)` isn't going to do what you want.  That will just be the size of the variable `input`, which is a pointer, so it will be a small, fixed quantity, like 4 or 8.  There is no way it can know how much space you requested from `malloc`, right?  So you need to use 256 for the size.

Comment: @Olaf No, you don't need to subtract one from the size.  `fgets` reads one less than the given size, leaving itself room for the null byte.

Comment: i will try with fscanf.

Comment: @olaf The freeing and closing happen outside of the snippet. I think the problem is that the fgets is reading all of the lines, but before it exits the loop it tries to add the null character to the char pointer array and causes a seg fault, I think that's the reason the last line doesn't print. Not because it isn't read, but because a segmentation fault is happening and canceling the print statement.

Comment: @DaneParchment: We can't identify problems in code you don't show. To have any chance of your problem being solved, you'll need to post a minimal compilable example that exhibits the problem. Don't post your entire program - strip it down until there is nothing left except the bare minimum to show the problem.

Comment: Certainly the problem is after `fgets(input, sizeof(input), ip)` which should be `fgets(input, 256, ip)`.  Since output is buffered, the last line is not printed and the seg fault appears to be in the loop.  Add `fflush(stdout)` after the `while()` and see the seg fault appear after all is printed.  The fault is later in unposted code, likely because it is making wrong assumptions about the data in `input[]`.  Bets are on `'\n'` is missing.

Comment: @chux, will try, I updated the code to show that I did in fact change the sizeof(input) to 256, I had tried that before I posted and still got the error, but was able to get some output when I did sizeof(input)....sorry about the rookie mistakes, still getting used to c.

Comment: Better to add a note about 256 than change your post.

Comment: P.S. Disagree about `fscanf()` advice.  `fgets()` is just fine with text files.

Comment: @DaneParchment: You cannot `free` the block later, because `input` goes out of scope.

Comment: @Olaf....hmmm didn't know that. We are just learning about C pointers in class, so wasn't to privy on how free works, so if I allocate memory to a pointer or what not within say a loop, directly after the loop ends and I am done messing with the data in the pointer is when I should free it?

Comment: @Schwern No, `fgets` reads at most *one character less* than the size it is given, so it always has room for a null byte.  I pointed this out to @Olaf in an earlier comment.  Read the man page.  256 is the correct size to pass in this instance.

Comment: @Dane You can free it whenever you wish, but you have to know the address when you do so.  If it is only stored in a variable that has gone out of scope, then you can't free it.  So either free it sooner, or else *save the address* somewhere so you can free it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys I found out what the problem was. I had my pointer malloc'd outside of the loop where it receives the character sequences from the input file. Because of this it was referencing the same location over, and over again....apparently this was causing issues when I tried to reference more than one line of code, as the *input variable was only pointing to the last line of the code. When I changed it to this:

```
else if(inputExists == 1) {
        //First open the file
        inputFile = fopen(inFile, "r");
        //If said file exists
        if(inputFile) {
            while(!feof(inputFile)) {
            char *temp2 = malloc(500);
            fgets(temp2, 500, inputFile);
            if((strlen(temp2)>0) && (temp2[strlen (temp2) - 1] == '\n')) {
                temp2[strlen (temp2) - 1] = '\0';
            }
            root = insert(root, temp2);
            }
        }else {
            printf("The file/directory you specified does not exist or won't open.\n");
        }
        fclose(inputFile);
    }
```

the code worked. Thanks for the help though guys/gals, it was greatly appreciated and I learned alot more about pointers and `fgets` in general

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems. To start with, `free` allocated memory.

```
free(input);
```

Also, file needs to be closed.

```
fclose(ip)
```